# UITableView Dynamic Datasource

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a slightly complicated table issue, I set up the table, and give it the number of sections, and number of rows per section.  I don't actually have any data for the cells, they are just empty at this point.

What I want to do is when the user scrolls the cells, make an API call and get the data for that cell plus let's say the next 50 cells.

The API call is asynchronous, and once I make that call I do not want to make it for the next cell as the user scrolls, because I know that data is coming back shortly.

Any ideas or suggestions?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Pull data for next 50 table view cells
    // The data will come from a server

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It should only be called when UITableView decides the row is needed. Try some `NSLog`ing to see what's really happening.

Comment: You can check the `indexPath` to determine if you are on the first row or on the last row. If you are on the last row, do the request again if not, don't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a great opportunity to introduce a separate service for managing your network requests instead of embedding that behavior in the middle of your table's datasource. If your datasource were to request that this service try to load the next 50 cells then that service can decide if it should actually start a new network request or not. Let your instance of that service keep track of what requests are in flight and what ranges of index paths they are expected to cover so it can decide when a `-shouldLoadItemsStartingAtIndexPath:` style message should result in a new network request.

Is that the sort of pattern you are looking for or did you have a more specific question about your approach?

Comment: @Vikings I'm suggesting that rather than perform network requests inside `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you should notify some other object of which cell the user is viewing and allow that object to decide what, if any, requests for additional data are needed as a result. The table view's delegate may implement `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` which would be a better place to identify when a cell becomes visible and consider requesting more.

Comment: I typically do it how @Jonah suggests. Always have the last cell be a special cell that when scrolled into view with delegate method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` invokes the loading of the next 50 items.  I usually put a loading spinner in it.

Comment: Thanks, I went with a solution very similar to this.